# Проверка занятости логина ajax.

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Такая проблема: для формы регистрации нужно сделать проверку доступности логина, но почему то при вводе логина, даже того который уже есть в базе всегда показывает что он свободен.

Сама форма

```
<form action="../lib/save_user.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="login" name="login" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" placeholder="логин">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
var login = $("#login").val();

$("#login").blur(function()
{
$("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Проверка...').fadeIn("slow");
//Проверить существует ли имя
$.post("../lib/check.php",{ login:login } ,function(data)
{
if(data=='no') //если имя не доступно
{
$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //начнет появляться сообщение
{ 
$(this).html('Это имя уже занято').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
}); 
}
else
{
$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() 
{ 
//тут прописывается сообщение о доступности имени
$(this).html('Имя доступно для регистрации').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1); 
});
}
});
});
});
```

php обработчик

```
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset= utf-8');

        include ("/lib/bd.php");

   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login'");
        $myrow = $result->fetch_array();
        $id = $myrow['id'];
        echo $id;
        if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        echo "no";
    }else{
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

Comment: а точно ли ../lib/check.php это правильный путь? в обработчике у вас написано если data == no, то чота делать, а во всех других вариантах -- свободен. это неправильно, ибо даже возврат 404 вернет "свободен".

Comment: посмотрите консоль, обрабатывайте именно success Ответ и error для запроса $.post

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите эти строчки

```
$id = $myrow['id'];
        echo $id;
        if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
        echo "no";
    }else{
        echo "yes";
    }
```

Первые 2 вообще лишние, можно сделать так

```
 if(isset($_POST['login']))
   {
     $login = $_POST['login'];

     $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login'");
     $myrow = $result->fetch_array();

     if ($myrow['id'] != $login) 
        {
          echo "Логин свободен";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Логин заннят";
        }
     }
```

Так даже более читабельней.

До обработчика php все доходит?

```
 if(isset($_POST['login']))
   {
     $login = $_POST['login'];

     echo $login; // Если выведет то все ок

     $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login'");
     $myrow = $result->fetch_array(); // тут все ок?

     if ($myrow['id'] != $login) 
        {
          echo "Логин свободен";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Логин заннят";
        }
     }
```

Comment: выдает логин занят не зависимо от того что было введено. Думаю проблема находится на стороне клиента в jquery скрипте, тк если запустить только сам php обработчик и передать ему в GET логин, то он определяет его занятость правильно.

Comment: Думаю неправильно передается значение логина с клиента

Answer (score 1):

Беглый взгляд...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var login = $("#login").val();
    ....
```

То есть вы получаете значение поля <input id="login" ... > только при загрузке страницы и больше его никак не обновляете? То есть получается, что посылаете на сервер пустую строку. Поместите получение значения в обработчик.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").blur(function(){
        var login = $("#login").val();
        ...
```

А по хорошему лучше строили бы приложения постепенно, а не сразу весь код в кучу. Сделать заготовку с проверками и потом постепенно добавлять функционал:

```
jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").blur(function(){
        var login = $("#login").val();
        $.post("../lib/check.php",{ login:login } ,function(data){
            alert(data);    
        });
    });
});

php:
header('Content-type: text/html; charset= utf-8');
include ("/lib/bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $query = "SELECT *FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login'";
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: отличный и правильный совет :)

Comment: возвращает пустой alert

Comment: а если так

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").blur(function(){
            var login = $("#login").val();
            $.ajaxError( function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) { 
               alert( event + ' ' + jqxhr + ' ' + settings + ' ' + exception );
            } );
            $.post("../lib/check.php",{ login:login } ,function(data){
                alert(data);    
            });
        });
    });

Comment: а вообще вместо `$.post` лучше использовать `$.ajax` ([JQuery.ajax][1]) , ибо

> If a request with jQuery.post()
> returns an error code, it will fail
> silently

[1]: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @thunder

> ...Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling.

т.е.

     $.post(url,success).error(failure)

Comment: @RageXL, в таком случае начните с самого малого и просто проверьте POST массив и значения Ajax:

    php:
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset= utf-8');
    include ("/lib/bd.php");
    $response = isset($_POST['login']) ? "POST: ".$_POST['login'] : "POST пустой";
    echo $response;

В Ajax проверьте сразу, что будет уходить:

    $("#login").blur(function(){
        var login = $("#login").val();
        alert("Отправлено: "+login);
        $.post("../lib/check.php",{ login:login } ,function(data){
            alert("Ответ: "+data);    
        });
    });

Comment: @eicto, да, но версию jquery мы не знаем, ошибок в консоли мы тоже не знаем, в первом комменте я советовал посмотреть в консоль, ибо терзают смутные сомнения, что путь до файла проверки неправильный, а в оригинальном скрипте "если не 'no', то все хорошо" же :) Но почему-то все это игнорируют и сразу в базу лезут :)

Comment: @thunder, в случае ошибки функция переданная $.post не выполняется и alert он бы не выдал. Поэтому мне кажется в консоли все чисто будет. Хотя перепроверить не мешает.

Comment: @thunder, ну если версия меньше 1.5... я обычно в этом случае просто рекомендую  апгрейдиться, ибо поддерживать такую рухлядь сам не стал бы и другим не советую.

Answer (score 0):

Я обработчик невкурил немного.

особенно вот эти строки

```
 $myrow = $result->fetch_row();
        $id = $myrow['id'];
        if (!empty($myrow[0])) {
```

которые никак не связаны между собой, и скорее проблема в этом.

UPD: http://www.php.net//manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: обновил код обработчика. В нем происходит следующее: со странице с формой передается значение введенного логина, далее идет выборка из базы по этому логину, если такой логин не найден, значит не существует его id и скрипт возвращает no, а если найден то yes.

Comment: @RageXL, года 3 назад я вот так делал.
if($query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login' LIMIT 1")->num_rows >=1) $error .= "Такой логин уже занят!";

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ' . $login);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "no";
    } else {
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

Через Firebug не плохо бы проверить посылается ли вообще запрос и с какими данными. Далее, экранируйте входящие данные, пропускайте через `mysqli_real_escape_sctring`. И еще - не выбирайте все подряд из базы, достаточно будет выбрать id и проверить, есть ли хоть 1 строка в результате. Если есть, значит пользователь с таким логином уже зарегистрирован.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

PHP:

```
 $login = $_POST['login'];
    $result =  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE login='$login'");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    echo "0";
}else{
    echo "1";
} }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").blur(function(){
$("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Проверка...').fadeIn("slow");
        var login = $("#login").val();
        $.post("check.php",{ login:login } ,function(data){

if(data == 0)      //если имя не доступно
{

$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //начнет появляться сообщение
{ 
$(this).html('Это имя уже занято').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
});
$("#login").val("");
}
if(data == 1)     //если имя доступно
{

$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() 
{ 
//тут прописывается сообщение о доступности имени
$(this).html('Имя доступно для регистрации').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1); 
});
}
            //  
        });
    });
});
```